# Call C function in DLL that returns char * from MS-Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, dll, vba

I have a DLL with a function declared like this:

```
char * __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI test(int x);
```

I want to call it in Access VBA like this:

```
Private Declare Function "test" Lib "MyDLL.dll"(ByVal x As Long) As String

Sub MySub
    Dim s As String
    s = test(1)
End Sub
```

Based on articles found in Google, I wrote a function in the DLL:

```
BSTR CStrToVBStr(char *str)
{
    int wslen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, lstrlen(str), 0, 0);
    BSTR bstr = SysAllocStringLen(0, wslen);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, strlen(str), bstr, wslen);
    return bstr;
}
```

After the call to test(), s apparently contains  Unicode characters. That is, a char * "test" is returned to VBA so that Mid(s, 1, 1) = "t", Mid(s, 2, 1) = Chr(0), Mid(s, 3, 1) = "e", etc. I decide to skip the conversion to Unicode and wrote CstrToVBStr as

```
BSTR CStrToVBStr(char *str)
{
    return SysAllocString(str);
}
```

and ignored the warning that SysAllocString takes an OLECHAR * and not a char * parameter.
The returned string looks good now, but the null character terminator is included, so if the char * is "test", then in VBA len(s) = 5 and Right(s,1) = Chr(0).

What is the right way to do what I am doing? All examples that I have seen are about char * as parameters, not return values. I can change test() to be

```
void __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI test(int x, char *result);
```

but I would like to know if what I am trying to do is possible.

I am using Access 2007 on Windows 7 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is the same as an `integer`. In VBA that means a `long` (as VBA uses 16 bit terminology). There are no strings involved. To convert an integer or char to a string use `chr(x)`.

Comment: I am returning a C string (char *, i.e., pointer to char), not char.